# Manipulate Pandas output when writing to a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to write something that will do the following:

read a CSV with upwards of 1m rows, and 100 columns of data;
summarize each column by listing the occurrence of duplicate rows from greatest number to least

What I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv (r'infile.csv')
outfile = ('outfile.csv')

for i in df:
    df.pivot_table(index=i, aggfunc='size').to_csv(outfile, mode='a')
```

This code outputs like so:

```
ColumnA,0
asdf,30
qwer,10
xyz,3
ColumnB,0
zxcv,50
jkl,8
```

I would prefer for the output to open in excel like this:

```
ColumnA    ColumnB
asdf 30    zxcv 50
qwer 10    jkl  8
xyz  3
```

or at least have the CSV like this:

```
ColumnA
asdf,30
qwer,10
xyz,3

ColumnB
zxcv,50
jkl,8
```

I have tried writing a blank line after each iteration in the for loop, but for whatever reason the blank lines are always all added at the end of the file - I think it has something to do with the way Pandas pushes the dataframes to the CSV? I dont know.

The CSV's do not use the same column headers, nor the same row values, nor are the amount of columns or rows reliably the same, so it must be able to create these lists based on what the CSV contains without user input.

I'm not opposed to adding each subset of data to a larger dataframe before outputting the data all at once if that is a possibility as well.

I'm entirely new to Pandas, and only a beginner in Python, so I dont know what is the best method to make this work.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: If you want top open your output in excel, I suggest you to use : 
df.to_excel()  
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html
instead of df.to_csv()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that gets you very close to the desired CSV output:

```
# create sample data
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''col_a, col_b, col_c
10, 20, 30
10, 21, 31
10, 21, 33
11, 22, 33
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=', ', engine='python')
print(df)

   col_a  col_b  col_c
0     10     20     30
1     10     21     31
2     10     21     33
3     11     22     33
```

Second, use `unstack()` to re-shape the data frame (i.e., the column labels become row labels).  And count number of values by `level=0` (the original column labels):

```
df = df.unstack().groupby(level=0).value_counts()

col_a  10    3
       11    1
col_b  21    2
       20    1
       22    1
col_c  33    2
       30    1
       31    1
dtype: int64
```

Finally, reset the index (row labels), make the column labels meaningful, and sort:

```
df = (df.reset_index()
 .rename(columns={'level_0': 'orig_col', 'level_1': 'orig_value', 0: 'num_occur'})
 .sort_values('orig_value')
 .sort_values('num_occur', ascending=False)
 .sort_values('orig_col')
)
print(df)

  orig_col  orig_value  num_occur
0    col_a          10          3
1    col_a          11          1
2    col_b          21          2
3    col_b          20          1
4    col_b          22          1
5    col_c          33          2
6    col_c          30          1
7    col_c          31          1
```

You can write the last version of the data frame to Excel.

Comment: This is close, however, I get: "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'". I should clarify that the columns and rows contain strings, numbers, symbols, and combinations of the three

Comment: Hi, I posted a second response below, that handles columns of different types.  If a single column has a mix of types (int, string, date in Col A), then you would probably have to convert everything to string first.

Comment: It seems that df.unstack().groupby(level=0).value(counts) produces the most human readable results that I can still process further without much difficulty. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that values within a column are a single type, and you can have strings in one column, integers in a second column, etc.  (If this is not correct, you could just convert everything to strings and use the first response).

```
# create test data -- different type for each column
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data2 = '''col_a, col_b, col_c
10, 'x', '2019-12-29'
10, 'y', '2019-12-29'
10, 'z', '2019-12-30'
11, 'z', '2019-12-31'
'''
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data2), sep=', ', engine='python', parse_dates=['col_c'])
```

Now use `value_counts()` on each column, and concatenate to make a wide table:

```
results = list()

for col in df2.columns:
    s = (df2[col]
         .value_counts()
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns = {'index': 'value', col: 'count'}))
    s.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[col], s.columns])
    results.append(s)
    
results = pd.concat(results, axis=1)
print(results)

  col_a       col_b            col_c      
  value count value count      value count
0  10.0   3.0   'z'     2 2019-12-29     2
1  11.0   1.0   'y'     1 2019-12-31     1
2   NaN   NaN   'x'     1 2019-12-30     1
```